# JSON mistmatching Key and value -difficult to parse in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, rest, kotlin, suspend

I have the following json

```
[
    {
        "abc": "",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "bcd": "",
        "type": "dropdown"
    },
    {
        "efg": "",
        "type": "dropdown"
    },
    {
        "hij": "",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "klm": "",
        "type": "string"
    }
]
```

I am facing difficulties in parsing the json in Kotlin.

How can i parse this JSON from Retrofit API - Kotlin Suspend Function?

Comment: Is the number of objects in this list fixed?

Comment: No it will dynamic, need to generate dynamic UI from this json. first key from the object will be label and "type" key will be define UI widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this json using mentioned function :

```
private void parseDynamicJson(JSONObject data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> keys = data.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray dataJSONArray = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = dataJSONArray.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseDynamicJson(dataJSONArray.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseDynamicJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("parseDynamicJson" + key + ":" + data.getString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("parseDynamicJson" + key + ":" + data.getString(key));
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: '@GET(ENDPOINT_TESTCODE)
    suspend fun getJsonData(@Header("Authorization") idtoken: String): 
    List<JSONObject>'
I am using Retrofit as i mentioned earlier - but i need to parse using POJO data class - i need guidance on it

Comment: This example will you : https://www.numpyninja.com/post/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-string